# Why we won't extract heat from air temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, atmospheric-science

There is a lot of energy in air's temperature? Why don't you harvest it? There is always difference that creates flow which can be piped into something converting it to mechanical energy...

Comment: All the wind turbines you see are doing exactly this.

Comment: That are not doing exactly that.

Comment: yes, they are.   There is a temperature difference which causes wind which is converted to mechanical energy by a turbine.

Answer (score 3):

Apart form what the other answers mention, also note that regardless of the energy conversion method, there is an upper limit for efficiency given by the Carnot efficiency:

$$\eta_{Carnot} =\frac{T_H-T_C}{T_H}$$

Efficiency is how much useful energy (such as mechanical work) you get out compared to how much thermal energy that must be absorbed. It is in general hopelessly inefficient to harvest energy from small temperature differences.

Comparing for example a $4\;^\circ \text C$ lake with ambient $34\;^\circ \text C$ air on a hot summer day will set the max upper efficiency limit at $\eta_{Carnot}=9. 7\;\%$. No machine is reaching it's max, so the realistic limit is far smaller.

Efficiency is a big factor when determining which devices that are worthwhile to put effort, money and time into.

Answer (score 2):

We actually do. The difference in air temperature causes a difference in pressure. The difference in pressure causes winds which then power wind turbines.

Comment: I tought of cooling hot air into ground...

Comment: The amount of power generated this way would probably be ridiculously small.

Answer (score 1):

We can only extract thermal energy from a temperature *difference*.

Since the air temperature *is* our surroundings, we can't  really extract the energy from it unless we had a lower temperature resovior.  See [exergy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exergy) for example.

Since we don't have something with large thermal capacity that is consistently cooler than the air, it's hard to extract the energy from the temperature of air.

On the other hand, temperatures drive all the wind energy in the atmosphere.  So in a way you can extract some of the thermal energy through wind turbines.

For low heating/cooling operations you can utilize a [geothermal heat pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geothermal_heat_pump) to take advantage of the temperature difference between underground and your surroundings.  Generally this is done between the ground source and your conditioned space though; and the outside air itself is not really taken into account (beyond heating cooling loads in the conditioned space).

The air itself is generally the *target* for the heating and cooling; so it's hard to use the air itself to provide energy for that process.

If you're talking energy generation, it's very useful to note that "low exergy" sources like geothermal produce very limited electrical energy, and are best utilized while kept in the thermal domain.

Comment: @azurinko Solar collectors get radiation from the sun, not from the air though, so that significant temperature difference has little relevance to the question.  I did forget about geothermal heat pumps, which is what you're referencing.

Comment: What about day/time difference with thermal buffer?

Comment: What about it?  I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: If I had just few tons of isolated water, it could act like thermal buffer, so in day it would get hot from air... (Just being runned trought heatsink) and at night it could provide heat... There is about ~20C difference, is it enought for heat engine to work atleast a little bit?

Comment: See Steevens answer.  The amount of work you get from it is basically negligible if you tried to get mechanical work.

Comment: I don't burn that much in day... If I use really small efficiency...

Answer (score 0):

We do "harvest" heat from the air in a [heat pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pump) (eg air conditioning unit) but work has to be done for the heat pump to work.
That work done to make the heat pump work is unfortunately less than the work that can be abstracted from the different temperature heat reservoirs created by the heat pump.

Nature does the job by having hot air (heated by the Sun) finding itself below cold air and creating convection currents.
So you now have moving air from which you can abstract (kinetic) energy.

Answer (score 0):

One way to create a temperature difference in ambient air is an airconditioner or heat pump, where heat energy is collected by a refrigerant from an area to be cooled, then compressed to increase it's temperature and transferred to an area that is to be heated (eg. clothes dryer or to heat a room). This process is made more efficient by expansion valve which cools the refrigerant below ambient temperature to gather more heat before undergoing compression again.

[Heat](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/work-and-energy/work-and-energy-tutorial/a/what-is-thermal-energy) is the lowest form of energy and converting it higher up the energy hierarchy wastes a lot of energy, so is better to keep it at heat energy and heat something that needs heating without converting higher forms of energy to heat (which is more convenient, profitable, wasteful and extremely efficient at creating waste heat) eg. electricity or gas for cooking or floor/pool heating, or hot water systems for showers and household plumbing, or heating a living room to watch tv or heat blanket for bed or even lighting up homes and streets with incandescent bulbs (that create light from heat)!

To answer your question, yes; heat can be extracted from air and converted into mechanical energy, by either heat turbines (hot water or steam medium), stirling engines or Seebeck Effect in peltier modules that generate electricity from heat, then drive an electric motor to give mechanical energy. [Incandescence](https://science.howstuffworks.com/light9.htm) and combustion create light from heat which can generate electricity in solar panels to drive electric motors for mechanical energy. Radiant heat can be concentrated with convex lenses to power solar cookers, boilers and transfer distilled water to higher ground for Gravitational Potential Energy, to be later released as electricity in turbines or provide water for drinking.

For next part of your question, it's not being harvested because it's not profitable, not commercially viable and not as fun as watching a dog racing to chase a piece of meat, or roosters fighting each other for no fault of their own or cars burning fuel to go around in circles generating smoke and heat (and people actually pay real money to go see them!) or people waiting for someone else to do it.